# Arch Linux unexpected shutdown

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, intel-graphics

I've installed Arch Linux on an Acer laptop with Intel Graphics (`GM965/GL960`).
I installed `Xorg`, `xf86-video-intel`, and the `XFCE4` desktop enviroment with `lightdm`. I can login and do stuff, but when I'm trying to move windows quickly or run some programs that use GUI, such as Eclipse, the computer suddenly shuts down and restarts without any messages. Is this a problem with the video driver or some other hardware?

Answer (score 2):

Hard shutdowns sound a lot like overheating. Are your laptop CPU's fan and heatsink clean and without dust? Perhaps it would be worth running some compressed air through to clean them up.

Another test you could do would be to use another distribution's Live CD, without installing it on the hard drive. This would allow you to rule out (or confirm) problems with the hardware.